# Add User to a Group in a localized MSI installer

Tags: wix

So I'm trying to create a MSI installer using Wix.

The Installer needs to add a new user to the Administrators group.

```
<util:Group Id="Administrators" Name="Administrators" Domain=[ComputerName] />
<Component Id="CreateUserAccount" Guid="*" Directory="TARGETDIR">
  <util:User Id="NewUser" Name="Test" Password="secret" UpdateIfExists="no" CreateUser="yes" PasswordNeverExpires="yes" PasswordExpired="no" RemoveOnUninstall="no" Domain="[ComputerName]">
     <util:GroupRef Id="Administrators" />
  </util:User>
</Component>
```

This code above works good on English OS'es but on any other language the "Administrators" doesn't exist

I tried adding:

`<util:Group Id="Administrators" Name="[WIX_ACCOUNT_ADMINISTRATORS]" Domain=[ComputerName]>`

But then it doesn't work on any OS since it prefixes the Administrator with a localized domain.

So I'm looking for a way to get "Administrators" localized anyone have any idea?
I guess I could try manipulate the `[WIX_ACCOUNT_ADMINISTRATORS]` to take everything to the right of the `\` but I have no idead how to write an inline script that does that.

EDIT: To be clear.
`[WIX_ACCOUNT_ADMINISTRATORS]` returns `BUILTIN\Administrators` for English OS and f.ex. `BUILTIN\Administratörer` for Swedish OS:es and I need to extract everything to the right of `\` to get the String that the `Util::Group` `Name` accepts

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I've started a discussion at: https://github.com/orgs/wixtoolset/discussions/7432 about this.

Comment: I think I did unfortunately I do not work at the company any more and sad enough I did not think about posting the solution here, possibly because it was only working for our use case.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested because I don't have any non-English VMs but try:

```
<PropertRef Id="WIX_ACCOUNT_ADMINISTRATORS"/>
<util:Group Id="AdministratorsGroup" Name="[WIX_ACCOUNT_ADMINISTRATORS]"/>
```

From:

https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/osinfo.html

Comment: Thanks but already got that part working the problem is that even for English it would return "BUILTIN\\Administrators" but the Util:Group doesn't find any group matching with "BUILTIN\Administrators" only "Administrators" in my Swedish Windows its "BUILTIN\Administratörer" and I need to extract the "Administratörer" and so on for other languages.

Comment: That sounds like a WiX bug.  As a work around you could write a custom action to trim off the BUILTIN\ part.

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible soon. I had created a [pull request](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix/pull/407) that was recently merged. When this is released you can do:

```
<PropertRef Id="WIX_ACCOUNT_ADMINISTRATORS_NODOMAIN"/>
<util:Group Id="AdministratorsGroup" Name="[WIX_ACCOUNT_ADMINISTRATORS_NODOMAIN]"/>
```